# Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value with IB Outlet

Tags: swift, xcode

Downloading image from Firebase want to show in tables:

[image]

I am getting an error `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`. I am trying to create an image outlet and beautify it

Answer (score 0):

Follow the belowing code structure.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as? cellViewClass {
        cell.profileDP()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`

I got this error when I was pushing label and image value from one controller to another view controller as below:

```
detailedVC?.imageTitleLabel.text = collectionItems.imageTitle[indexPath.row]
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailedVC!, animated: true)
```

Here the problem was I was assigning value to label outlet:
`detailedVC?.imageTitleLabel.text` which is not yet available, because another view controller is not yet loaded, So we can not use IBoutlet of another view controller's in our current view controller.

So Solution for that is here:
Create property in another view controller as below:

```
class DetailedCollectionViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var natureImage: UIImageView!
    
    // Property to get Title of image from previeous screen
    var imageTitle = ""
       
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("Image Title on Detailed VC: \(imageTitle)")
        // Set Values in Outlets
        imageTitleLabel.text = imageTitle
        natureImage.image = UIImage(named: imageTitle)
    }
}
```

And then use this property in the current View Controller to set a value as below:

```
detailedVC?.imageTitle = collectionItems.imageTitle[indexPath.row]
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailedVC!, animated: true)
```

Best Luck :)